# verilog alu design why all my output result is always 00000000

Tags: verilog, iverilog

Here is my code, the professor say module format cannot be changed. And the homework also require only the input can be load when rst_n=1, and the output should be 0 when rst_n = 0. But in test bench all my result always is 00000000, zero is 1, cout is 0, overflow is 1, what's the problem with my code?

I thought the problem maybe are here, but I have no idea how to edit it.
(I use //problem to mark to line in code below)

```
cout = out; //problem       
result = results; //problem       
result <= 32'b0; //problem
```

[image]
[image]

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module ALU_1bit(
    input               src1,       //1 bit source 1  (input)
    input               src2,       //1 bit source 2  (input)
    input               Ainvert,    //1 bit A_invert  (input)
    input               Binvert,    //1 bit B_invert  (input)
    input               Cin,        //1 bit carry in  (input)
    input       [2-1:0] operation,  //2 bit operation (input)
    output reg          result,     //1 bit result    (output)
    output reg          cout        //1 bit carry out (output)
    );

/* Write your code HERE */

reg temp1;
reg temp2;
reg temp3;
reg temp4;
reg temp5;

always@(src1 or src2 or Ainvert or Binvert or Cin or operation)
  begin
  case (Ainvert)
    1'b0:  temp1 = src1;   // 0
    1'b1:  temp1 = ~src1;   // 1
  endcase
  //$display("temp1 %d", temp1);
  case (Binvert)
    1'b0:  temp2 = src2;   // 0
    1'b1:  temp2 = ~src2;   // 1
  endcase
  //$display("temp2 %d", temp2);
  temp3 = temp1 & temp2;
  temp4 = temp1 | temp2;
  {cout, temp5} = temp1 + temp2 + Cin;
  //$display("temp3 %d", temp3);
  //$display("temp4 %d", temp4);
  //$display("temp5 %d", temp5);
  case (operation)
    2'b00:  result = temp3;   // AND
    2'b01:  result = temp4;   // OR
    2'b10:  result = temp5;    // addition
    2'b11:  result = temp5;    // addition
  endcase
end

endmodule


module alu(
    input                   rst_n,         // negative reset            (input)
    input        [32-1:0]   src1,          // 32 bits source 1          (input)
    input        [32-1:0]   src2,          // 32 bits source 2          (input)
    input        [ 4-1:0]   ALU_control,   // 4 bits ALU control input  (input)
    output reg  [32-1:0]    result,        // 32 bits result            (output)
    output reg              zero,          // 1 bit when the output is 0, zero must be set (output)
    output reg              cout,          // 1 bit carry out           (output)
    output reg              overflow       // 1 bit overflow            (output)
    );

/* only below can be edit */
wire [32-1:0]results;
wire out;
wire carryout0,  carryout1, carryout2, carryout3, carryout4, carryout5, carryout6, carryout7, carryout8, carryout9, carryout10, carryout11, carryout12, carryout13, carryout14, carryout15, carryout16, carryout17, carryout18, carryout19, carryout20, carryout21, carryout22, carryout23, carryout24, carryout25, carryout26, carryout27, carryout28, carryout29, carryout30;
ALU_1bit UUT0(src1[0], src2[0], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[1:0], results[0], carry0);
ALU_1bit UUT1(src1[1], src2[1], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry0, ALU_control[1:0], results[1], carry1);
ALU_1bit UUT2(src1[2], src2[2], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry1, ALU_control[1:0], results[2], carry2);
ALU_1bit UUT3(src1[3], src2[3], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry2, ALU_control[1:0], results[3], carry3);
ALU_1bit UUT4(src1[4], src2[4], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry3, ALU_control[1:0], results[4], carry4);
ALU_1bit UUT5(src1[5], src2[5], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry4, ALU_control[1:0], results[5], carry5);
ALU_1bit UUT6(src1[6], src2[6], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry5, ALU_control[1:0], results[6], carry6);
ALU_1bit UUT7(src1[7], src2[7], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry6, ALU_control[1:0], results[7], carry7);
ALU_1bit UUT8(src1[8], src2[8], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry7, ALU_control[1:0], results[8], carry8);
ALU_1bit UUT9(src1[9], src2[9], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry8, ALU_control[1:0], results[9], carry9);
ALU_1bit UUT10(src1[10], src2[10], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry9, ALU_control[1:0], results[10], carry10);
ALU_1bit UUT11(src1[11], src2[11], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry10, ALU_control[1:0], results[11], carry11);
ALU_1bit UUT12(src1[12], src2[12], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry11, ALU_control[1:0], results[12], carry12);
ALU_1bit UUT13(src1[13], src2[13], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry12, ALU_control[1:0], results[13], carry13);
ALU_1bit UUT14(src1[14], src2[14], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry13, ALU_control[1:0], results[14], carry14);
ALU_1bit UUT15(src1[15], src2[15], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry14, ALU_control[1:0], results[15], carry15);
ALU_1bit UUT16(src1[16], src2[16], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry15, ALU_control[1:0], results[16], carry16);
ALU_1bit UUT17(src1[17], src2[17], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry16, ALU_control[1:0], results[17], carry17);
ALU_1bit UUT18(src1[18], src2[18], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry17, ALU_control[1:0], results[18], carry18);
ALU_1bit UUT19(src1[19], src2[19], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry18, ALU_control[1:0], results[19], carry19);
ALU_1bit UUT20(src1[20], src2[20], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry19, ALU_control[1:0], results[20], carry20);
ALU_1bit UUT21(src1[21], src2[21], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry20, ALU_control[1:0], results[21], carry21);
ALU_1bit UUT22(src1[22], src2[22], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry21, ALU_control[1:0], results[22], carry22);
ALU_1bit UUT23(src1[23], src2[23], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry22, ALU_control[1:0], results[23], carry23);
ALU_1bit UUT24(src1[24], src2[24], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry23, ALU_control[1:0], results[24], carry24);
ALU_1bit UUT25(src1[25], src2[25], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry24, ALU_control[1:0], results[25], carry25);
ALU_1bit UUT26(src1[26], src2[26], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry25, ALU_control[1:0], results[26], carry26);
ALU_1bit UUT27(src1[27], src2[27], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry26, ALU_control[1:0], results[27], carry27);
ALU_1bit UUT28(src1[28], src2[28], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry27, ALU_control[1:0], results[28], carry28);
ALU_1bit UUT29(src1[29], src2[29], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry28, ALU_control[1:0], results[29], carry29);
ALU_1bit UUT30(src1[30], src2[30], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry29, ALU_control[1:0], results[30], carry30);
ALU_1bit UUT31(src1[31], src2[31], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry30, ALU_control[1:0], results[31], out);

always@(posedge rst_n) begin
  cout = out; //problem
  result = results; //problem
  zero = ~(|result);
  overflow = result[31] ^ cout;
end

always@(negedge rst_n) begin
  result <= 32'b0; //problem
  zero = 0;
  overflow = 0;
end

endmodule
```

testbench

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module testbench;

parameter PATTERN_NUMBER = 6'd30;

reg          clk;
reg          rst_n;
reg [32-1:0] src1_in;
reg [32-1:0] src2_in;
reg  [4-1:0] operation_in;

reg  [8-1:0] mem_src1   [0:(PATTERN_NUMBER*4-1)];
reg  [8-1:0] mem_src2   [0:(PATTERN_NUMBER*4-1)];
reg  [8-1:0] mem_opcode [0:(PATTERN_NUMBER-1)];
reg  [8-1:0] mem_result [0:(PATTERN_NUMBER*4-1)];
reg  [8-1:0] mem_zcv    [0:(PATTERN_NUMBER-1)];

reg  [6-1:0] pattern_count;
reg          start_check;
reg  [6-1:0] error_count;
reg  [6-1:0] correct_count;
reg  [6-1:0] error_count_tmp;

wire [32-1:0] result_out;
wire          zero_out;
wire          cout_out;
wire          overflow_out;

wire  [3-1:0] zcv_out;
wire [32-1:0] result_correct;
wire  [3-1:0] zcv_correct;
wire  [4-1:0] opcode_tmp;

    assign zcv_out = {zero_out, cout_out, overflow_out};
    assign opcode_tmp = mem_opcode[pattern_count];
    assign result_correct = {mem_result[4*(pattern_count-1) + 5'd3],
                            mem_result[4*(pattern_count-1) + 5'd2],
                            mem_result[4*(pattern_count-1) + 5'd1],
                            mem_result[4*(pattern_count-1) + 5'd0]};
    assign zcv_correct = mem_zcv[pattern_count-1];

initial begin
    clk   = 1'b0;
    rst_n = 1'b0;
    src1_in = 32'd0;
    src2_in = 32'd0;
    operation_in = 4'h0;
    start_check = 1'd0;
    error_count = 6'd0;
    correct_count = 6'd0;
    error_count_tmp = 6'd0;
    pattern_count = 6'd0;

    $readmemh("src1.txt", mem_src1);
    $readmemh("src2.txt", mem_src2);
    $readmemh("op.txt", mem_opcode);
    $readmemh("result.txt", mem_result);
    $readmemh("zcv.txt", mem_zcv);

    #100 rst_n = 1'b1;
    start_check = 1'd1;

    //$dumpfile("alu.vcd");
    //$dumpvars(0,testbench);
end

always #5 clk = ~clk;

alu alu(
    .rst_n(rst_n),
    .src1(src1_in),
    .src2(src2_in),
    .ALU_control(operation_in),
    .result(result_out),
    .zero(zero_out),
    .cout(cout_out),
    .overflow(overflow_out)
);


always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(pattern_count == (PATTERN_NUMBER+1)) begin
        if(error_count == 6'd0) begin
            $display("*      Congratulation! All data are correct!      *");
            $display("***************************************************");
            $display("Correct Count: %2d", correct_count );
        end
        else begin
        end
        $finish;
    end
    else if(rst_n) begin
        src1_in         <= {mem_src1[4*pattern_count + 6'd3],
                            mem_src1[4*pattern_count + 6'd2],
                            mem_src1[4*pattern_count + 6'd1],
                            mem_src1[4*pattern_count + 6'd0]};
        src2_in         <= {mem_src2[4*pattern_count + 6'd3],
                            mem_src2[4*pattern_count + 6'd2],
                            mem_src2[4*pattern_count + 6'd1],
                            mem_src2[4*pattern_count + 6'd0]};
        operation_in    <= opcode_tmp;
        pattern_count   <= pattern_count + 6'd1;
    end
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(start_check) begin
        if(pattern_count==0) begin
            $display("***************************************************");
            $display("*             PATTERN RESULT TABLE                *");
            $display("***************************************************");
            $display("* PATTERN *              Result             * ZCV *");
            $display("***************************************************");
        end
        else if(pattern_count < (PATTERN_NUMBER+1)) begin
            if(result_out == result_correct) begin
                if(zcv_out != zcv_correct) begin
                    $display("* No.%2d error!                                    *",pattern_count);
                    $display("* Correct result: %h     Correct ZCV: %b   *",result_correct, zcv_correct[3-1:0]);
                    $display("* Your result: %h        Your ZCV: %b      *",result_out, zcv_out);
                    $display("***************************************************");
                    error_count <= error_count + 6'd1;
                end
                else begin
                    correct_count <= correct_count + 6'd1;
                end
            end
            else begin
                $display("* No.%2d error!                                    *",pattern_count);
                $display("* Correct result: %h     Correct ZCV: %b   *",result_correct, zcv_correct[3-1:0]);
                $display("* Your result: %h        Your ZCV: %b      *",result_out, zcv_out);
                $display("***************************************************");
                error_count <= error_count + 6'd1;
            end
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

result error

```
***************************************************
*             PATTERN RESULT TABLE                *
***************************************************
* PATTERN *              Result             * ZCV *
***************************************************
* No. 1 error!                                    *
* Correct result: eeeeeeee     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 3 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 9bf5fea6     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 4 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000000     Correct ZCV: 110   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 5 error!                                    *
* Correct result: fffffffe     Correct ZCV: 001   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 6 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 70459a76     Correct ZCV: 011   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 7 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 7530eca9     Correct ZCV: 010   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 8 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000001     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No. 9 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.11 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.12 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000000     Correct ZCV: 110   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.13 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000000     Correct ZCV: 110   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.14 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000001     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.15 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000000     Correct ZCV: 110   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.16 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 000000ff     Correct ZCV: 010   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.18 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000001     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.21 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 00000001     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.22 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.23 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 12345678     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.24 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 02244220     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.26 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.27 error!                                    *
* Correct result: 97755779     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.28 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
* No.30 error!                                    *
* Correct result: ffffffff     Correct ZCV: 000   *
* Your result: 00000000        Your ZCV: 100      *
***************************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not run it through any tool but please try this:

```
wire carryout0,  carryout1, carryout2, carryout3, carryout4, carryout5, carryout6, carryout7, carryout8, carryout9, carryout10, carryout11, carryout12, carryout13, carryout14, carryout15, carryout16, carryout17, carryout18, carryout19, carryout20, carryout21, carryout22, carryout23, carryout24, carryout25, carryout26, carryout27, carryout28, carryout29, carryout30;
wire [31:0] results;
ALU_1bit UUT0(src1[0], src2[0], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[2], ALU_control[1:0], results[0], carry0);
ALU_1bit UUT1(src1[1], src2[1], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry0, ALU_control[1:0], results[1], carry1);
ALU_1bit UUT2(src1[2], src2[2], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry1, ALU_control[1:0], results[2], carry2);
ALU_1bit UUT3(src1[3], src2[3], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry2, ALU_control[1:0], results[3], carry3);
ALU_1bit UUT4(src1[4], src2[4], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry3, ALU_control[1:0], results[4], carry4);
ALU_1bit UUT5(src1[5], src2[5], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry4, ALU_control[1:0], results[5], carry5);
ALU_1bit UUT6(src1[6], src2[6], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry5, ALU_control[1:0], results[6], carry6);
ALU_1bit UUT7(src1[7], src2[7], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry6, ALU_control[1:0], results[7], carry7);
ALU_1bit UUT8(src1[8], src2[8], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry7, ALU_control[1:0], results[8], carry8);
ALU_1bit UUT9(src1[9], src2[9], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry8, ALU_control[1:0], results[9], carry9);
ALU_1bit UUT10(src1[10], src2[10], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry9, ALU_control[1:0], results[10], carry10);
ALU_1bit UUT11(src1[11], src2[11], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry10, ALU_control[1:0], results[11], carry11);
ALU_1bit UUT12(src1[12], src2[12], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry11, ALU_control[1:0], results[12], carry12);
ALU_1bit UUT13(src1[13], src2[13], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry12, ALU_control[1:0], results[13], carry13);
ALU_1bit UUT14(src1[14], src2[14], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry13, ALU_control[1:0], results[14], carry14);
ALU_1bit UUT15(src1[15], src2[15], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry14, ALU_control[1:0], results[15], carry15);
ALU_1bit UUT16(src1[16], src2[16], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry15, ALU_control[1:0], results[16], carry16);
ALU_1bit UUT17(src1[17], src2[17], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry16, ALU_control[1:0], results[17], carry17);
ALU_1bit UUT18(src1[18], src2[18], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry17, ALU_control[1:0], results[18], carry18);
ALU_1bit UUT19(src1[19], src2[19], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry18, ALU_control[1:0], results[19], carry19);
ALU_1bit UUT20(src1[20], src2[20], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry19, ALU_control[1:0], results[20], carry20);
ALU_1bit UUT21(src1[21], src2[21], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry20, ALU_control[1:0], results[21], carry21);
ALU_1bit UUT22(src1[22], src2[22], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry21, ALU_control[1:0], results[22], carry22);
ALU_1bit UUT23(src1[23], src2[23], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry22, ALU_control[1:0], results[23], carry23);
ALU_1bit UUT24(src1[24], src2[24], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry23, ALU_control[1:0], results[24], carry24);
ALU_1bit UUT25(src1[25], src2[25], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry24, ALU_control[1:0], results[25], carry25);
ALU_1bit UUT26(src1[26], src2[26], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry25, ALU_control[1:0], results[26], carry26);
ALU_1bit UUT27(src1[27], src2[27], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry26, ALU_control[1:0], results[27], carry27);
ALU_1bit UUT28(src1[28], src2[28], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry27, ALU_control[1:0], results[28], carry28);
ALU_1bit UUT29(src1[29], src2[29], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry28, ALU_control[1:0], results[29], carry29);
ALU_1bit UUT30(src1[30], src2[30], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry29, ALU_control[1:0], results[30], carry30);
ALU_1bit UUT31(src1[31], src2[31], ALU_control[3], ALU_control[2], carry30, ALU_control[1:0], results[31], cout);

always@(posedge rst_n) begin
  result = results;
  zero = ~(|results);
  overflow = results[31] ^ cout;
end

always@(negedge rst_n) begin
  result <= 32'b0;
  zero = 0;
  overflow = 0;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: There is no grammatical error. But in test bench all my result is 00000000, zero is 1, cout is 0, overflow is 1,

Comment: Play around with these always blocks, sensitivity list should be updated - add there results signal or use (*).